# How do I set X coordinate of button without changing: y, width, height

Tags: c++, winapi

I know I can use MoveWindow to move it but I only want to move the button on the x axis. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can get the button's (screen) position using GetWindowRect, then you can use ScreenToClient to get it's location in the form. Example:

```
RECT buttonScreenRect;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &buttonScreenRect);

POINT buttonClientPoint;
buttonClientPoint.x = buttonScreenRect.left;
buttonClientPoint.y = buttonScreenRect.top;

ScreenToClient(hwnd, &buttonClientPoint);

MoveWindow(hwnd, 50, buttonClientPoint.y, buttonScreenRect.right - buttonScreenRect.left, buttonScreenRect.bottom - buttonScreenRect.top);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You should update your question to reflect what you actually wanted to ask.  There is no way anyone could have figured out your real problem was "how do I translate from screen to client coordinates" from your initial question.